# TeamCity run pytest in a docker-compose environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, pytest, teamcity

I have a question regarding a build configuration in teamcity

We are developing a python (flask) rest api where a sql database holds the data.
Flask server and postgresql server each runs in a docker container.
Our repository contains a docker-compose file which starts all necesary containers.

Now I want to set up a build configuration in TeamCity where the repository is pulled, containers are build and then the docker-compose file should be up and all test functions (pytest) in my flask-python application should be run. I want to get the test report and the docker-compose down command should be run.

My first approach using a command line build configuration step and issuing the commands works, but i don't get the test reports. I not even getting the correct exit code (test fails, but build configuration marked as success)

Can you give me a hint what would be the best strategie to do this task.
Building, Testing, Deploying a application which is build out of multiple docker containers (i.e. a docker-compose file)

Thanks
Jakob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working with a similar configuration: a FastAPI application that uses Firebase Emulator suite to run pytest cases agains. Perhaps you will find these build steps suitable for your needs too. I get both test reports and coverage using all the built-in runners.

Reading the TeamCity On-Premise [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2021.2/docker-wrapper.html#how-it-works-1), I found that running a build step command within a docker container will pick up `TEAMCITY_DOCKER_NETWORK` env var if previous steps ran docker-compose. This variable is then passed to your build step that runs in docker via `--network` flag, allowing you to communicate with services started in `docker-compose.yml`.

Three steps are required to get this working (please ignore numbering in the screenshots, I also have other steps configured):

1. Using Docker runner, build your container where you will run pytest. Here I'm using the `%build-counter%` to give it a unique tag.

[image]

2. Using Docker Compose runner, bring up other services that your tests rely on (postgresql service in your case). I am using `teamcity-services.yml` here because `docker-compose.yml` is already used by my team for local development.

[image]

3. Using Python runner, run Pytest within your container that was build in step 1. I use suggested [teamcity-messages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/teamcity-messages) and [coverage.py](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/), which get installed using `pip install` inside the container before executing pytest. My container already has pytest installed, if you look through "Show advanced options" there's a checkbox that will let you "Autoinstall the tool on command run" but I haven't tried it out.

[image]

Contents of my `teamcity-services.yml`, exposing endpoints that my app uses when running pytest.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  firebase-emulator:
    image: my-firebase-emulator:0.1.13
    expose:
      - "9099" # auth
      - "8080" # firestore
      - "9000" # realtime database
    command: ./emulate.sh -o auth,firestore,database
```

A hypothetical `app/tests/test_auth.py` run by pytest, which connects to my auth endpoint on `firebase-emulator:9099`. Notice how I am using the service name defined in `teamcity-service.yml` and an exposed port.

```py
def test_auth_connect(fb):
    auth = fb.auth.connect("firebase-emulator:9099")
    assert auth.connected
```

In my actual application, instead of hardcoding the hostname/port, I pass them as environment variables which can also be defined using TeamCity "Parameters" page in the build configuration.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i needed. The trick is to have a seperate docker-compose.yml (teamcity-services.yml in your Case) without the actual application for testing in teamcity server.

Comment: Exactly. Keeping the testing environment separate from the application in docker-compose.yml was the key in this approach. On the flip-side, I now have to keep 2 files up to date, my `docker-compose.yml` that's used by the developers for local env, and `teamcity-services.yml` for CI.

Comment: Maybe you can simplify this situation by using a docker-compose.yml file and override it either with docker-compose.teamcity.yml or docker-compose.override.yml (for local Dev)